# Convert HTML-table to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, html-table, office365

I am trying to convert an HTML-table to an Excel table. The problem is that Excel changes the table in the following way:

- Text converted to date
- Numbers in parentheses are now negative.
- Numbers are rounded or truncated.
- All horizontal lines are removed.

Below is an example of a HTML-table opened in Excel 2016 by right-clicking the table, choosing "open with excel".

[image]

Is this possible to do? (without having manually revert the changes).

**Example table**

The raw html table can be downloaded here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rasmusrhl/stuff/master/table.html

and as webpage here:
https://rasmusrhl.github.io/stuff/

Answer (score 1):

I can solve *one* of your issues. Sorry about the others :(

- Open Excel and create a new empty spreadsheet
- Choose `From Web` on the Data ribbon Enter the URL of your HTML
- Click `Go` to load the HTML
- Click `Options` in top-right of the toolbar
- Tick `Disable date recognition`
- Now click `Import`